# How to instantiate Eq (or any class) for a type with different constructors Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a doubt about this thing.

If I have this type:

```
data Person = Person {name :: String, age :: Int} 

data Example = Constructor1 Integer | Constructor2 Person
```

I want to instantiate Eq class for Example

```
instantiate Eq Example where
(==) (Constructor1 e1) (Constructor1 e2) = e1 ==e2
(==) (Constructor2 e1) (Constructor2 e2) = e1 == e2
```

We can supposed that I have already instantiated the Eq class for Person, so I can compare Person with Person.

This is the way for instantiate a class with a type with multiple constructors?

And other doubt. Should I add a comparation between Constructor1 and Constructor2. I don't think so, because they could be from different types.

I'm talking about something like this stuff:

```
(==) (Constructor1 e1) (Constructor2 e2) == "no idea how to compare Person with Int"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I add a comparation between Constructor1 and Constructor2?

You have to, otherwise your implementation of `Eq` would be incomplete.

After all your cases, just add

```
(==) _ _ = False
```

> I don't think so, because they could be from different types.

But they are of the same type, they are both `Example` values.

So your `Eq` function needs to be able to compare them.

If you think it makes sense to have a `Constructor1 number` and a `Constructor2 person` be equal under some conditions you can write the appropriate predicate to do that. But that seems unusual and you should probably make your own typeclass for this kind of comparison instead of using `Eq`. If you do use `Eq`, make sure it satisfies reflexivity, transitivity and symmetry.

---

Also note that for "boring" mechanic `Eq` instances, the compiler can derive them automatically (and it will create the same thing you would have written anyway):

```
data Example = Constructor1 Integer | Constructor2 Person
  deriving Eq
```

You can also derive `Show`.

https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/28gxxz/how_does_deriving_eq_work/

Answer (score 5):

> Should I add a comparation between `Constructor1` and `Constructor2`. I don't think so, because they could be from different types.

Well that is of course up to you, you could specify that `Constructor1 i` is equal to `Constructor2 p` given that `age p == fromIntegral i`, so that `Constructor1` basically holds an "age" and `Constructor2` is equal that constructor given the age of that person has that age, but that depends on *what you* consider two equal `Example`s. As long as your function satisfies the [*equivalence relation conditions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition) there is no problem.

If you do not want any `Constructor1` object to be equal to `Constructor2`, you should add a line that returns `False` in that case:

```
instance Eq Example where
    (==) (Constructor1 e1) (Constructor1 e2) = e1 == e2
    (==) (Constructor2 e1) (Constructor2 e2) = e1 == e2
    (==) _ _ = False
```

But you can save you the trouble in that *specific* case, and just write:

```
data Example = Constructor1 Integer | Constructor2 Person deriving Eq
```

Haskell then implement an `instance Eq` automatically, where two `Example` objects are considered equal given the *data constructors* are the same, and all the parameters are *equal*. In all other cases the two objects are considered *not* equal.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just do

```
data Example = Constructor1 Integer | Constructor2 Person
    deriving (Eq)
```

? Then the compiler will instantiate `Eq` for you.

If you want to do it manually, then yes, you should add a case for comparing different constructors. If the standard library didn't do this, then e.g. `True == False` would throw an exception (`True` and `False` are different constructors of the `Bool` type) and so would `"hello" == ""` (`""` is `[]` (at type `[Char]`) and `"hello"` is `'h' : "ello"`, so again you have different constructors (`[]` and `:`)).

You can do it like this:

```
instance Eq Example where
    (==) (Constructor1 e1) (Constructor1 e2) = e1 == e2
    (==) (Constructor2 e1) (Constructor2 e2) = e1 == e2
    (==) _ _ = False
```